# Inline assembly, SEHException

Tags: c#, windows, assembly, x86

I have created a .dll file in cpp to access the I/O ports and write to them.For this purpose I am calling this .dll from my c# console application but when try to run it, I get "SEHException was unhandled" exception. Do you have any idea?

this is c#:

```
[DllImport("testlib.dll")]
public static extern void enableWatchDog();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    enableWatchDog();
}
```

this is cpp (which creates .dll):

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void enableWatchDog() { 
   _asm {
      mov al, 41
      out 66, al
      mov al, 4
      out 62, al
   }
}
```

Comment: there is no need for inline assembly, just use the `__outbyte` instrisic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yxkhewh Also, would be helpful to know which part threw the exception, your asm, the C#, the interop etc.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but unfortunately in this time i am getting "Privileged instruction". Maybe win7 does not allow me to reach the I/O ports. Any idea?

Comment: its possible you don't have the required access to write to IO ports, from the intel manuals, OUT instruction, exceptions section: `#GP(0): If the CPL is greater than (has less privilege) the I/O privilege
level (IOPL) and any of the corresponding I/O permission bits in
TSS for the I/O port being accessed is 1`. what the required access level is, I'm not sure, you might need to be a kernel driver or just run in ring3, or use memory mapped IO ports.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access arbitrary I/O ports directly from user mode applications in Windows. You need to use a special kernel mode driver for that.